# will vector reallocate when push_back after shrink capacity to zero?

Tags: c++

1. before push back, i shrink capacity to zero, then i push back item into vector, will it reallocate?
2. is reallocate means slow down in performance?
3. if so, why need to shrink capacity to zero or fit the size?

   ```
   vector<int> mandy2(5);
   vector<int>().swap(mandy2);

   printf("mandy2 size: %d\n", mandy2.size());
   printf("mandy2 capacity: %d\n", mandy2.capacity());

   mandy2.push_back(1);
   mandy2.push_back(2);
   mandy2.push_back(6);
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> before push back, i shrink capacity to zero, then i push back item into vector, will it reallocate?

Yes it will.

Reference the **[doccumentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/)**:

`void push_back ( const T& x );`

> Adds a new element at the end of the vector, after its current last element. The content of this new element is initialized to a copy of x.
>
> This effectively increases the vector size by one, **which causes a reallocation of the internal allocated storage if the vector size was equal to the vector capacity before the call**. Reallocations invalidate all previously obtained iterators, references and pointers.

---

> Is `reallocate` means slow down in performance?

Theorotically,Yes!
How much it hurts you can only be conclusively said after profiling your code for the same.

---

> If so, why need to shrink `capacity` to zero or fit the `size`?

You do that only, if you know that you do not want to add any further elements to the vector, that ensures your vector does not consume more memory than you would actually need ever.

Comment: @種瓜得瓜種豆得豆: `Profiling` in simple words means `measuring`, in this case it would be measuring the time taken, which would tell us if an operation is performance intensive. Several tools are available for the same, you can google for the same.

Answer (score 2):

**`std::vector` will reallocate whenever the capacity is insufficient to accommodate the `push_back` request.**

> before push back, i shrink capacity to zero, then i push back item
>   into vector, will it reallocate?

Yes.

> is reallocate means slow down in performance?

In the long run, no (since each insertion takes `O(1)` amortized time). I wouldn't worry about it unless profiling shows it *is* a problem.

> if so, why need to shrink capacity to zero or fit the size?

I don't understand this question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes.
2. Yes, probably. It also means that iterators, pointers and references to elements in the container are invalidated.
3. Shrinking the capacity will reduce the memory usage of the container. This will free up memory for other parts of the program to use.